# How to calculate percentages from data frame columns, when the data frame size is variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose we have the below starting data frame called "data", with generating code beneath it (note that in this example the starting data frame is static, whereas in the actual code this is used in the data frame is generated by a function where the size of the data frame (rows and columns) varies based on the actual data the function is run against):

```
> data
   To A  B  C Sum
1   A 1  3  5   9
2   B 2  4  6  12
3   C 3  5  7  15
4 Sum 6 12 18  36

library(dplyr)
    
data <- 
  data.frame(
    To = c("A","B","C"),
    A = c(1,2,3),
    B = c(3,4,5),
    C = c(5,6,7)
  )
    
data <- data %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Sum")))
data <- cbind(data, Sum = rowSums(data[,-1]))
```

I am trying to create a new data frame that calculates each cell value from the starting data frame "data" as a percentage of its respective column total, so we end up with a data frame that looks like this (call it "data1")(but please note the caveat below this data frame):

```
   To     A      B      C    Sum
1   A 0.167  0.250  0.278  0.250
2   B 0.333  0.333  0.333  0.333
3   C 0.500  0.417  0.389  0.417
4 Sum 1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000
```

**Caveat**: the size of the starting data frame ("data") is variable in the actual code based on the data it is run against, and not static like in this MWE. So the percentage formula needs to reach to the value in the last row of each column to use in the denominator in the percentage calculation. Fixed references (such as `data[2,4]` for first column total) won't work.

Any suggestions for an efficient way to do this? With a preference for `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
data |> 
  mutate(across(-c(To), ~ ./.[To == "Sum"])) |> 
  as_tibble()

# A tibble: 4 x 5
  To        A     B     C   Sum
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     0.167 0.25  0.278 0.25 
2 B     0.333 0.333 0.333 0.333
3 C     0.5   0.417 0.389 0.417
4 Sum   1     1     1     1
```

Comment: Very sleek. I would not have figured out syntax like -c(To), and ~./. on my own. Little by little, through questions/answers like these, I learn. Thank you.